# Is there any way to set a flag by default for a git command?

Tags: git

I would like that whenever I run `git diff` or `git show` it silently automatically appends `--ignore-all-space`.  Is there a way to do this?  I know that I can create aliases like this:

> ```
> [alias]
>    sh = show --ignore-all-space
>    di = diff --ignore-all-space
> ```

But I would like to use the `diff` and `show` commands directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think so:

- I do not see any "`--ignore-all-space`" option for git show
- I cannot see `git diff` having the `--ignore-all-space` set automatically: it has to be passed as argument.

One solution for git diff at least would be to use `git difftool`.
Since it is a script (in `<git>/libexec/git-core`), you could modify that script to call `git diff` with that option always set.

But, that may not prove a good idea, since it can lead to ignore changes that not even *you*, the sender, had any chance to detect and test.

Comment: using --ignore-all-space with git show does seem to work, even if it's not documented

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [`core.whitespace` configuration variable](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).