# Setting git default flags on commands

Tags: git, logging

I want to know if there is a way to set a flag by default for git command. Specifically, I want to set the `--abbrev-commit` flag so that when executing `git log`, I want to execute `git log --abbrev-commit`.

Unlike the question "[is there any way to set a flag by default for a git command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278296/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-flag-by-default-for-a-git-command)", there is apparently not a configuration flag for adding --abbrev-commit to git log. Furthermore, the git manual states that I cannot create an alias: ["To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing git commands are ignored"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-alias)

My third option is to invent a new alias like `glog=log --abbrev-commit` in my .gitconfig file. But I'd rather not invent my own DSL with new commands.

Is there another way to achieve it so that the `abbrev-commit` flag is set by default??

Comment: As of git 1.7.6 there is a flag to control this behavior.  See the answer by @underrun below.

Comment: As of ~2022-March/Git 2.35.1, there *still* doesn't appear to be a way to set default flags for common Git commands (outside of shell wrapper around `git` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510960/7650275)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204925/7650275)]). I would like to see Git offer an option within .gitconfig to point commands to aliases. Alternatively, a new config category/group "prepend", where could define something like `prepend.log = "--stat --find-renames --stat-count=5"; prepend.diff = "blahblahblah"`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Since git version 1.7.6, git config has gained a log.abbrevCommit option which can be set to true. Thus the answer is upgrade to at least 1.7.6 (current as of this writing is 1.7.11.4) and use:

```
git config --global log.abbrevCommit true
```

Comment: Don't suppose there's an option for oneline?

Comment: I am accepting this answer. Nice to see Git added this configuration since I wrote the question almost four years ago.

Comment: Where is the source of all these mystical options?

Comment: Anyone know the default flag for graph? I can't find it in the page @xaxxon linked..

Comment: @myol, you should use `git config --help` or `git help config` to get the documentation **matching your installation**.

Comment: Be forewarned. This setting will affect all displays of hashes in the log, including those for other built-in formats like `--pretty` and `--format=medium` unless you add `--no-abbrev-commit`

Comment: @Zaz for oneline use `git config --global format.pretty oneline` [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875528/37899](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875528/37899)

Answer (score 52):

You can use a custom format to have `git log` mimic `--abbrev-commit` by default:

```
git config format.pretty "format:%h %s"
```

Comment: Great, this is easily the best answer.

Comment: You can also use colors while formatting: "%C(yellow)%h%Creset %s" will present like git log --oneline with colors.

Comment: Now a quick question: if you found this useful and this answers exactly the problem, why don't you mark this as correct?

Comment: This is better if you don't want to remember obscure or hard to remember aliases and prefer to just use "git log" all the time.

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen I think this should be the correct answer, not what had been accepted above

Comment: @ShyamHabarakada Looking upon it, the answer from underrun is actually most correct for the versions of Git mentioned, so I change my accept to that question.

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen I didn't notice the version of git in the questions, but I think you mean the version of git you have (had?) doesn't support the format.pretty config?

Comment: This was the best answer for me. The `log.abbrevCommit` setting affected other more verbose formats, which I didn't like.  Also, use `%C(auto)%h %s` to get the normal oneline format with automatic coloring. I used `git config --global format.pretty "%C(auto)%h %d %s"` because I wanted decorated oneline as my "default"

Answer (score 41):

There is no generic mechanism in git to set default arguments for commands.

You can use [git aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) to define a new command with the required arguments:

```
git config alias.lg "log --oneline"
```

Then you can run `git lg`.

Some commands also have configuration settings to change their behavior.

Comment: I want to avoid creating my own syntax so I'd prefer a solution where I don't use `git lg` but `git log`

Comment: why? what difference would it make?

Comment: The very important difference is that I don't want to introduce "Jespers git syntax" on my system. I want me (and others using my machine) to use the generic commands. Also, this will make my work faster on other machines: I don't worry about accidentally typing "git lg" and getting a "not found" error

Comment: I am accepting this answer as a valid solution. Even though this is what I originally described as my best option in the question, it seems it is the best solution at the moment.

Comment: If someone else was using your machine and typed git log your intended solution would mean that they would be getting results that they didn't expect.

Comment: Redefining standard aliases can break scripts.

Comment: Scripts should not assume what options might be in effect, and be more explicit about specifying what they want.

Comment: @Abizern yes but you still have global configuration that does exactly that, so you're essentially saying _"don't configure your git globally because changing its behavior is bad."_

Answer (score 16):

I like the `git log --oneline` format.
To get it as default, use

`git config --global format.pretty oneline`

Credit: https://willi.am/blog/2015/02/19/customize-your-git-log-format/

Comment: Is there something like this for `git tag`?

Comment: Answered my own Q. There is: `git config --global tag.sort version:refname`

Answer (score 10):

VonC has already hinted at a shell wrapper in his answer; here is my Bash implementation of such a wrapper. If you put this e.g. into your `.bashrc`, your interactive shell will support overriding of Git built-in commands as well as uppercase aliases.

```sh
# Git supports aliases defined in .gitconfig, but you cannot override Git
# builtins (e.g. "git log") by putting an executable "git-log" somewhere in the
# PATH. Also, git aliases are case-insensitive, but case can be useful to create
# a negated command (gf = grep --files-with-matches; gF = grep
# --files-without-match). As a workaround, translate "X" to "-x".
git()
{
    typeset gitAlias="git-$1"
    if type ${BASH_VERSION:+-t} "$gitAlias" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        shift
        eval $gitAlias '"$@"'
    elif [ "$1" = "${1#-}" ] && expr "$1" : '.*[[:upper:]]' >/dev/null; then
        # Translate "X" to "-x" to enable aliases with uppercase letters.
    translatedAlias=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/[[:upper:]]/-\l\0/g')
        shift
        command git "$translatedAlias" "$@"
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

You can then override `git log` by putting a script named `git-log` somewhere into your PATH:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec git log --abbrev-commit "$@"
```

Answer (score 8):

I have a similar issue (many of the default options for Git commands are dumb). Here's my approach. Create a script called 'grit' (or whatever) on your path, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=$1
shift 1
if [ "$cmd" = "" ]; then
  git
elif [ $cmd = "log" ]; then
  git log --abbrev-commit $@
elif [ $cmd = "branch" ]; then
  git branch -v $@
elif [ $cmd = "remote" ]; then
  git remote -v $@
else
  git $cmd $@
fi
```

Very straightforward to read and maintain, in case you need to share it with Bash non-experts.

Comment: Do you really want "git remote blah" to call "git branch blah"?

I'm using a variant of this where I put git earlier in the path and then explicitly call /usr/bin/git in my script.  Yeah this probably breaks something.

Comment: I liked this and made two additional tweaks.  I made it a bash function and let it be named `git` by adding a first line to get the real command path: `thegit=\`/usr/bin/which git\``. And I added an option to cancel the overrides with an x before the command like `git x log ...`: `if [ "$cmd" = "x" ]; then; $thegit $@`.

Comment: I would pair this wrapper with a git alias - the wrapper would call the alias, e.g. `git mycustomlog` (rather than the specific customized command). This allows the Git customizations to live in global git config and customized per project config, maybe more.

Answer (score 1):

A mixing of **Steve Bennett's** and **PotatoFarmer's** ideas above, but fully dynamic needing no script updates as well as allowing per-project flags by leveraging git's "alias" feature and our own convention: Anything prefixed with "my-" gets our treatment, otherwise it's just passed on.  I have this as "~/bin/my_git" and use an alias in *.bashrc* to use it in place of git (`alias git="$HOME/bin/my_git"`):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

cmd=${1:-}
shift 1

if [ "$cmd" = "" ]; then
    git
# Ask git itself if we have a "my-<cmd>" version to prefer
elif git config --list | egrep -q "^alias\.my-$cmd="; then
    git my-$cmd $@
else
    git $cmd $@
fi
```

And of course matching entries as desired in `~/.gitconfig` and/or your project's `.git/config` file:

```
[alias]
    my-merge = merge --no-commit
    my-log = log --name-status
```

Answer (score 0):

Every utility we use (svn, maven, git, ...) are always encapsulated in a .bat (on Windows, or .sh on Unix), in order to offer our developers one directory to add to their path.

If git is encapsulated in a wrapper script, then... everything is possible.

But that remains a solution linked to the user's setup, not linked to Git itself or the git repo.

Comment: So you mean i should be able to achieve it by adding alias to my .bash_profile?

Comment: @Jesper: that is the idea, since your wrapper git.bat will be able to detect what Git command you want to execute and could add any option it wants.