# Why does git say a sub project is dirty if I do not have any sub-modules in my repository?

Tags: git, subproject

Its a new git repository and all I've done is added a whole lot of code to it. However, it tells me:

```
+Subproject commit 62402f4a7e3aa34a5f22532c8c699836b7ae4967-dirty
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873980/git-tells-me-my-subproject-is-dirty-what-does-this-mean), this seems to imply that this has something to do with sub modules and is to be expected if you have sub modules.

However, I do not have any. Why am I getting this message and how do I get of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure there aren't some unintended .git folders in subdirectories of your repo.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I deleted the .git folder and my working directory is now clean.

Comment: @carleeto you do mean .git from a subdirectory and not root right?

Comment: I would, if the site would let me. Apparently, I need to wait 6 minutes :)

Comment: Yeah. The .git folder inside the subdirectory.