# How do I revert my changes to a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git submodule (RestKit) which I have added to my repo.

I accidentally changed some files in there and I'd like to go back to the source version. In order to do that, I tried to run

```
Mac:app-ios user$ git submodule update RestKit
```

But as you can see here, this did not work as it is still "modified content":

```
Mac:app-ios user$ git status
...
#   modified:   RestKit (modified content)
```

Even

```
Mac:app-ios user$ git submodule update -f RestKit
```

doesn't revert locally modified files.
How do I reset the content of that submodule?

Comment: If `git reset --hard` doesn't work, first try specifying the remote branch with `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>`.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Move into the submodule's directory, then do a `git reset --hard` to reset all modified files to their last committed state. Be aware that this will discard all non-committed changes.

Comment: git submodule update (even without the --init) worked for me to abandon the submodule "changes" when I hadn't actually changed anything. If you go to the submodule directory and git status comes up empty, try this instead of the reset.

Comment: `git submodule update --init` worked for me; without `--init` it didn't work at all.

Comment: reset --hard didn't work for me, my submodule still couldn't be deinit because of local changes.

Comment: in addition to @markshiz, `git submodule update -f --init` for my case.

Comment: For me only `git submodule update --init --recursive` worked.

Comment: If there are recursive submodules, `git reset --hard --recurse-submodules` should help

Answer (score 485):

A more fail-safe method than all previous answers:

```
git submodule deinit -f .
git submodule update --init
```

The first command completely "unbinds" all submodules, the second then makes a fresh checkout of them.
It takes longer than the other methods, but will work whatever the state of your submodules.

If your sub-modules have their own sub-modules, instead of second command, try:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --checkout
```

Where `--recursive` is obvious, but `--checkout` prevents "`Skipping submodule ...`" (see [skip details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63974886/8740349)).

Comment: Regrettably this did not work in my case (with modified local files in a git submodule), the "update --init" command spews `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout`

Comment: To update specific submodule do: $ git submodule deinit -f -- <submodule_path> and then $ git submodule update --init -- <submodule_path>

Comment: I tried all methods above until I got to this one. For me, this is the only one that got my git looking "clean" (without the `*` in my `PS1` that `git status -uno` was unable to explain).

Comment: Leaving a comment for future me - This one worked. Try it first.

Comment: I needed to repeat this to get it to work (I'm pulling a *very* heavy codebase from git). If it doesn't work first time, I suggest trying again, maybe twice.

Comment: Yep. This one did the trick for me, too.

Comment: I had to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` instead.

Answer (score 392):

If you want to do this for all submodules, without having to change directories, you can perform

```sh
git submodule foreach git reset --hard
```

You can also use the recursive flag to apply to all submodules:

```sh
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
```

Comment: this works so much better for automation than trying to cd into each submodule directory.

Comment: Note that you may also want to `git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -x -f -d`

Comment: on my machine (Windows using Git 2.22.0) I need single quotes around the second git command when using the --recursive flag or it won't work: git submodule foreach --recursive 'git clean -x -f -d '

Comment: You should call it with sudo, in case when there are write protected files.

Comment: doesn't work for me. new commits are still highlighted red. `git restore` doesn't work either

Comment: solved by method2 on this page (basically the answer below): https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-reset-all-submodules-in-git/

Answer (score 93):

Well for me, having

```
git reset --hard
```

just reset the submodule to the state where it checked out, not necessary to the main's repo referenced commit/state. I'll still have "modified contents" like OP said. So, in order to get the submodule back to the corrects commit, I run:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Then when I do `git status`, it's clean on the submodule.

Comment: regretfully `submodule update --init` does not seem to revert local modifications in my case anyway :|

Comment: This was the right answer for me, since I had just done a `git pull` inside my submodule. Using update I was able to go back to the commit referenced by my main module

Comment: I should be able to upvote this answer every time I have to look it up, because I obviously can't remember it.

Answer (score 56):

do 4 steps sequential:

```
git submodule foreach git reset --hard HEAD
git submodule update
git submodule foreach "git checkout master; git pull"
git submodule foreach git clean -f
```

Comment: question, if the submodule is new, there will not be a .git file inside that directory, correct? will the git command bubble to the parent repo?

Comment: @jiahut Even after doing this, I still have "(new commits") next to my submodule when doing 'git status' from the parent?

Comment: @DavidDoria `git submodule update` was what fixed the `(new commits)` for me.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to discard all changes in the entire repository along with submodules, you can use:

```sh
git restore . --recurse-submodules
```

> **Note** that this only undoes all local-changes (in repository, and in all sub modules).
>
> But `git reset ...` takes a target-commit-id as input, and can move `HEAD` to any commit.

Comment: this is my best answer as i dont wanna other submodule being downloaded, just the one in such folder

Answer (score 38):

This worked for me, including recursively into submodules (perhaps that's why your -f didn't work, cause you changed a submodule inside the submodule):

```
git submodule update -f --recursive
```

Answer (score 23):

First try this, as others have said:

```
git submodule update --init
```

If that doesn't work, change to the submodule directory and use the following command to see if there are any changes to the submodule:

```
git status
```

If there are changes to your submodule, get rid of them.  Verify that you can don't see any changes when you run "git status".

Next, go back to the main repository and run "git submodule update --init" again.

Answer (score 13):

Since Git 2.14 (Q3 2017), you don't have to go into each submodule to do a `git reset` (as in `git submodule foreach git reset --hard`)

That is because git reset itself knows now how to recursively go into submodules.

See [commit 35b96d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35b96d1de8e795aeac8ec281e88e59f2778335e7) (21 Apr 2017), and [commit f2d4899](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2d48994dc11ba367e92c38c8025c3354418145a), [commit 823bab0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/823bab09c68b4048e433ab48b9185302c2f4b63a), [commit cd279e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd279e2e1b4f41f0272d90abb2ba5a06c544b3da) (18 Apr 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5f074ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f074ca7e8ddccb6471e457d7a3f85c1fe00e21a), 29 May 2017)</sup>

> ### builtin/reset: add --recurse-submodules switch

`git-reset` is yet another working tree manipulator, which should be taught about submodules.

> When a user uses git-reset and requests to recurse into submodules,
>   this will reset the submodules to the object name as recorded in the
>   superproject, detaching the HEADs.

**Warning**: the difference between:

- `git reset --hard --recurse-submodule` and
- `git submodule foreach git reset --hard`

is that the former will also reset your main parent repo working tree, as the latter would only reset the submodules working tree.
So use with caution.

Answer (score 12):

It is simple:

```
cd /path/to/submodule/root
git submodule update -f --init  .
```

Most answers are suggesting resetting all the submodule, which I think is not the best approach as there might be legit changes in them.

Comment: seems simply `git submodule update -f --init /path/to/submodule` would work

Answer (score 7):

For git <= 2.13 these two commands combined should reset your repos with recursive submodules:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
git submodule update --recursive --init
```

Answer (score 4):

My way to reset all submodules (*without* detaching & keeping their `master` branch):

```sh
git submodule foreach 'git checkout master && git reset --hard $sha1'
```

Comment: What is $sha1 ?

Answer (score 4):

If there's changes in your submodules, then use

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard
```

If your changes are remote submodule changes, then use

```
git submodule update --init
```

If these changes have been committed, then use

```
git reset --hard
git submodule update --init
```

Answer (score 3):

This works with our libraries running GIT v1.7.1, where we have a DEV package repo and LIVE package repo.  The repositories themselves are nothing but a shell to package the assets for a project. all submodules.

The LIVE is never updated intentionally, however cache files or accidents can occur, leaving the repo dirty.  New submodules added to the DEV must be initialized within LIVE as well.

**Package Repository in DEV**

Here we want to pull all upstream changes that we are not yet aware of, then we will update our package repository.

```
# Recursively reset to the last HEAD
git submodule foreach --recursive git reset --hard

# Recursively cleanup all files and directories
git submodule foreach --recursive git clean -fd

# Recursively pull the upstream master
git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master

# Add / Commit / Push all updates to the package repo
git add .
git commit -m "Updates submodules"
git push
```

**Package Repository in LIVE**

Here we want to pull the changes that are committed to the DEV repository, but not unknown upstream changes.

```
# Pull changes
git pull

# Pull status (this is required for the submodule update to work)
git status

# Initialize / Update 
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 2):

The [currently most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27415757/658014) (`deinit` and `update`) gets rid of every non tracked file.

A way to achieve the same result but keep non tracked files around is to directly checkout all submodules to the commit the parent is pointing to:

```
git submodule update --checkout --force
```

The command is a bit faster too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I do it this way:

1. Go to the submodule path

   `cd <submodule_path>`
2. Check the last commit hash

   `git log`
3. Reset the change to that last commit hash

   `git reset --hard <commit_hash>`