# Git one-liner to revert unwanted submodule change

Tags: git

So, let's say I messed up and ran `git commit -a`, accidentally committing a submodule change that I didn't want (probably because I ran `git pull` and forgot to run `git submodule update` afterwards). I want to get rid of this change. Is there a one-liner I can use to do this?

The way I do this today, is:

1. I run `git show` to figure out what the old hash was
2. I `cd` into the submodule, and I run `git reset --hard OLD_HASH`
3. Go back to parent directory and `git commit --amend -a`

This is too many steps. Is there really nothing shorter?

NB: This question is different from [How do I revert my changes to a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906554/how-do-i-revert-my-changes-to-a-git-submodule) where the user accidentally made actual changes to files in the submodule. In this case, no files were edited in the submodule; I just updated the commit pointer in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can *write* a one-liner, by writing a script.  The script itself is inevitably going to be more than one line.  It can be those three lines, if you like, or some other set of three or so lines (e.g., `git rev-parse`, a carefully-constructed `git update-index`, and `git commit --amend`).  You can make that script into a Git command (by naming it `git-foo` and putting it in your path, after which `git foo` will run your `git-foo` script) or make it into a Git alias using `git config` and the `[alias]` section.

You might want to set your settings so that it's less likely to happen in the future, using `submodule.recurse` to `true` for instance.  (Note that this affects `git push` unless you also set `push.recurseSubmodules`; peruse all the submodule settings in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more).