# Unable to update git sub-modules

Tags: git, git-submodules

In my project, i am using sub-modules to manage the dependencies.

I ran the command once and the repos are cloned and fetched.

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Now, I have deleted the folder (_internals) in which they were cloned.

when running the command again, it does not fetch anything.

Not Sure whats wrong. Any pointers or help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have not gone through [this answer](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_bugs)

To Quote it:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules --jobs=10

**a feature git first learned in 1.8.5.**
```

Until the [bug](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_bugs) is fixed, for the first time you do need to run

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Or try running:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

Can you try this: Move into the submodule's directory, then do a git reset --hard to reset all modified files to their last committed state. Be aware that this will discard all non-committed changes. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10906596/6517383

Comment: I tried both the ways. 

But it says "already up to date". But the folders in which the code repos were there is deleted. 

But there is no code.

Comment: Can you try this:
```Move into the submodule's directory, then do a git reset --hard to reset all modified files to their last committed state. Be aware that this will discard all non-committed changes.```
From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10906596/6517383