# Why would 'git submodule update' skip a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo with a single submodule `sub/x`.  (This submodule does not contain any submodules of its own.)

In the superproject's repo, the output of `git status` shows the following (unstaged) modification

```
modified:   sub/x (new commits)
```

If I now run

```
git submodule update
```

...on the superproject, the following line gets printed to the terminal (and nothing more):

```
Skipping submodule 'sub/x'
```

After this, the output of `git status` on the superproject remains as shown above, unchanged.

(Ditto if I add `--init` to the `git submodule update` command.)

**Q:** How can I determine why `git submodule update [--init]` skips the `sub/x` submodule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Note: I've only checked a very recent Git version, and the submodule code has been undergoing changes, so this might not be the only case.  But it is the only place that message can occur in the latest Git.)

**Edit 2:** it seems that the case below applies when the superproject's `.git/config` has an explicit `update = none` setting in it.  That makes more sense than the guess I made below; it's the first half of the `||` expression here.  I assumed there was no `update = none` setting though, and we were getting this from the second half (unspecified and type=NONE) and I still find that confusing.

(original answer continues below)

---

This message appears in [the Git submodule helper code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/385c171a018f2747b329bcfa6be8eda1709e5abd/builtin/submodule--helper.c#L2101-L2107):

```
        if (suc->update.type == SM_UPDATE_NONE
            || (suc->update.type == SM_UPDATE_UNSPECIFIED
                && update_type == SM_UPDATE_NONE)) {
                strbuf_addf(out, _("Skipping submodule '%s'"), displaypath);
                strbuf_addch(out, '\n');
                goto cleanup;
        }
```

This code fires when there's no `submodule.name.update` setting set in the superproject's `.git/config` for the given submodule, and the update type is unspecified (`git submodule update` without `--checkout`).  So:

```
git submodule update --checkout
```

would override this, as would configuring the submodule's update setting to `checkout`.  **Edit:** I don't understand *why* the code is this way: [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) says that the default is `checkout`, and behaving differently with the actual setting set to `checkout`, vs defaulting to `checkout`, does not seem to match this claim.

Comment: There's an actual `none` update type it's looking for

Comment: This is an interesting idea; I can't wait to try it.  Unfortunately, I'll have to wait until tomorrow, because the system I'm doing this on *just* went down for maintenance...

Comment: @jthill: there is, but this seems to apply only to the default (`SM_UPDATE_UNSPECIFIED`; I did a quick search). There's also this odd notion of active vs inactive submodules, but that seems not to relate to the "skipping" message. I don't understand the *intent* behind this code, as the documentation says that unset means checkout.

Comment: @jthill: sure enough, the superproject's `.git/config` file had the setting `update = none` for the `sub/x` submodule.  I have no idea why this setting is there.  I know for a fact that I did not add it by manually editing this `.git/config` file.  Some other `git` command must have adding this setting as a side-effect.

Comment: The situation that gave rise to this post has the hallmarks of my "bull in the China shop" phase: (1) a Git repo that is in a bizarrely borked state, needing hours and hours of troubleshooting, and (2) me not having the faintest idea of how the repo got to such a state. I entered such a phase when I started using Git-with-submodules, but I went through a very similar phase (which lasted for weeks) several years ago, when I first started using (plain, i.e. no-submodules) Git.  ...

Comment: ...I didn't get past it until I (1) understood Git's fundamental underlying structure and how it is implemented, in very concrete terms; (2) understood how the various Git commands modify this underlying structure; and (3) learned the commands needed to interrogate this structure, for troubleshooting.  I need the same thing for Git-with-submodules, but I don't know how to get it.  It's going to be some rough weeks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your submodule itself is ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- sub/x
```

Check also the `.gitmodules` file, [for any `ignore` directive](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_the_configuration_of_submodules).

Comment: Thanks, but both of these came up empty.  My version of `git` does not have `check-ignored`, but it does have `check-ignore`.  When I ran the command line you posted with `check-ignore` instead of `check-ignored`, I got no output.  The `.gitmodules` file has only the `path`, `url`, and `branch` directives for this one module (and nothing else).

Comment: @kjo What version of Git do you have? On which OS?

Comment: @kjo Is there a `sub/x/.git` subfolder which would make `x` a nested repository, in addition of its submodule status?

Comment: the Git version is 2.17.0; the OS is Linux (CentOS); there is a sub/x/.git *file*, not a subfolder.

Comment: Ok. First test to check, see if the issue persists with git 2.28