# Can I detect the change of sub project?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm building up C.I system for my project. My project is managed by Git and has two sub modules. I found that teamcity cannot detect the change of submodule. Is there any way to detect the change of submodule without setting up additional C.I projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by another user in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902469/teamcity-keeping-git-submodule-up-to-date):

> You could add a step which will checkout, from the parent repo, if a
>   submodule has any modified file.

As mentioned in that answer, to checkout you could do:

> To undo all changes to your submodule just `cd` into the root
>   directory of your submodule and do `git checkout` .

For the shorter method you could do `git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

Does your submodule require authentication? There are number of issues in the tracker that might cause this behaviour: [TW-35594](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-35594), [TW-34281](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-34281), [TW-23300](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23300), [TW-24809](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24809)