# Superproject commit on submodule does not show "From .. To"

Tags: git, git-submodules

I know this question is similar to: [Git diff says subproject is dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873980/git-diff-says-subproject-is-dirty) but it does not display that the diff is dirty. The diff on one of my super project commits for a file shows:

```
diff --git a/xxxxxxx b/xxxxxxx
index 9e3b445..1a0c23c 160000
--- a/xxxxxxxx
+++ b/xxxxxxxxxx
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 9e3b44599d56c87bae711ba47ea103e79afe5049
+Subproject commit 1a0c23c8b90c8053286d1b13d3ec63f7768d39a7
```

Shouldn't it show something like:

```
Submodule xxxxxx Change

From:   9e3b44599d56c87bae711ba47ea103e79afe5049

                    2 weeks ago (2/11/2018 4:32:00 PM)

        Zero pad Home Score and Away Score

To:     1a0c23c8b90c8053286d1b13d3ec63f7768d39a7

                    4 days ago (2/18/2018 4:48:10 PM)

        Zero pad minutes and seconds
```

Every time I commit something or look at the diff on the unstaged local changes, I see this same problem on this submodule. I have other submodules in this superproject but don't have this problem. Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `xxxxxxx` is actually a submodule, registered in your `.gitmodules`, or if it is a simple gitlink (SHA1 entry in your main project index).

A gitlink would generate that kind of diff, since it does not know its upstream repository and is not considered as a submodule.