# Xcode loses git history when moving a file

Tags: xcode, git

I'm trying to move a file between two projects in the same git repository.  In Xcode, I can move the references to the new project fine but as soon as I physically move or copy the files to the new projects folder, git loses all of the log/blame history.

On the command line I can do `git log --follow` and that works but how do I do that in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set a global option for git log, but you might be able to override it and trick Xcode into running a modified git log with the follow option appended.

Try building on this hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204925/949284