# How to always show full-history in Git?

Tags: git

I'm using Intellij and command-line Git and we have problems with not seeing commits because Git defaults to not showing "uninteresting" changes.

For example, if Developer "A" changes something and pushes the change, then Developer "B" changes it back to the way it was (before "A"'s change) and pushes that change, those commits would not show in the history because they would cancel each other out (at least this is the way it's been explained to me.)  This makes it hard to find problems and leads to a lot of "Where'd my change go?"

Ideally both Intellij and command-line would show full history, all commits, including merges, every time, by default.

Anyone know the settings to accomplish this in .gitconfig?

EDIT:  The following section is from the [git-log documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and explains what I mean by "uninteresting changes"

*Default mode
Simplifies the history to the simplest history explaining the final state of the tree.         Simplest because it prunes some side branches if the end result is the same (i.e. merging branches with the same content)
--full-history
Same as the default mode, but does not prune some history.*

Comment: What do you mean with "uninteresting changes"?

Comment: How do you lose commits because of what you see in a log view?  Git always shows all commits in every tool I've used.

Comment: @AndrewMyers git-log excludes "uninteresting commits" by default, meaning commits that are treesame to a parent.  See "History Simplification" in the documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html

Comment: See if this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500586/setting-git-default-flags-on-commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show full history with `git log` invoke it with the `--sparse` and `--full-history` switches.

```
--sparse

    All commits that are walked are included.

    Note that without --full-history, this still simplifies merges: if one of
    the parents is TREESAME, we follow only that one, so the other sides of the
    merge are never walked.
```

Note that there is no way to [specify default flags for git commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500586/setting-git-default-flags-on-commands) so you will have to create an alias for your command line git use. I am not aware of IntelliJ supporting such setup for git log.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but maybe someday this will be configurable in both command line and Intellij.

Comment: If you guys just scrolled down a little on the link you posted, you'd see that there is a way to specify default flags for git commands since version 1.7.6

Comment: @Cole9350 Please read the Q&A you refer to - the version 1.7.6 functionality is **specific for log.abbrevCommit and nothing else**. It isn't applicable to the switches discussed here.

Comment: @mockinterface Your post clearly reads "Note that there is no way to specify default flags for git commands so you will have to create an alias for your command line git use." Which you can agree is false, perhaps you should be more specific to the "commands" your referring to

Comment: @Cole9350 If you wish to interpret my comment in the strict terms of first order logic, predicate calculus and existential quantification, you are free to do so. To me it is clear that having [a default flag hacked in](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v7-Add-log-abbrevCommit-config-variable-td6378803.html), entirely unrelated to this post, doesn't count as default flags support.