# Can I use fetch recurseSubmodules on git clone set in .gitconfig

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a way to set in .gitconfig to git clone automatically add --recurse-submodules flag ? I trie to add in .gitconfig the following:

```
[fetch]
    recurseSubmodules = true
```

But it doesn't work.

```
$ git clone upstream nowyprojekt2
Cloning into 'nowyprojekt2'...
done.
```

I need to add the --recurse-submodule flag

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodule upstream nowyprojekt2
Cloning into 'nowyprojekt2'...
done.
Submodule 'euca2ools' (https://github.com/eucalyptus/euca2ools.git) registered for path 'euca2ools'
Cloning into 'euca2ools'...
remote: Counting objects: 19147, done.
remote: Total 19147 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 19147
Receiving objects: 100% (19147/19147), 22.23 MiB | 450.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (15556/15556), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'euca2ools': checked out '12c358cd27ff652cb144de124bb5472a74145277'
```

My GIT version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not available, even in the latest Git 2.5 released today.

That leaves you with an alias (or git alias) workaround, in order to replace a [`git clone --recursive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) by one command (similar to "[Setting git default flags on commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502218/6309)").

Comment: That's a shame. Nvertheless thanks a lot for confirmation. Btw. it is --recursive not --recurse as an alternative for --recurse-submodules

Comment: @mas tes, I have fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

The currently highest-rated answer is not true anymore, you can indeed set a (global) config to always add `--recursive-submodules`. Just set it via

```
git config --global fetch.recurseSubmodules yes
```

(possible values are `yes`, `no`, `on-demand`, docs are here https://git-scm.com/docs/fetch-options#Documentation/fetch-options.txt---recurse-submodulesyeson-demandno)

Comment: doesnt work for me 
git version 2.34.1
https://git-scm.com/docs/fetch-options/2.33.0

Indeed fetching yes, but cloning no
First you have to clone the repo, run submodule update --init
then git fetch fetches also the submodules

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. `git clone` takes the `--config` flag, which initialises the repo with some given config params. you should be able to do `git clone --config fetch.recurseSubmodules [my-repo]`.