# Git canceling flags

Tags: git

I have set some git options globally (not aliased) thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500586/setting-git-default-flags-on-commands), so that my git log shows `--oneline` by default.

Sometimes I want to see the expanded version to see the date of previous commits. How can I 'cancel' a flag temporarily? - or alternatively, what is the flag that shows the expanded view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to "cancel" a flat set in the global or repository config.

Just specify the format you want using [`--pretty`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) and the command line flags override any flag specified in the repository or global config.

For example:

```
$ git log --pretty=medium
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override configuration options on the command line, e.g.:

```
git -c log.abbrevCommit=false log
```

In your case set

```
git -c format.pretty=short log
```

You can also bind this to an explicit command with a `git alias` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

From the [git manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_formatting),

```
--oneline
       This is a shorthand for "--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit" used together.
```

Given this, if you look at the other options, we see that something like `--no-abbrev-commit --pretty=medium` should give something close to what you want.