# Gitk: Setting "Ignore space change" option to be true by default

Tags: git, git-diff, gitk, git-config

Is this possible in any way? I have tried `git config --global alias.diff 'diff -b -w'` but unfortunately that was not the solution.

Comment: And why wasn't it the solution? (as illustrated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500586/setting-git-default-flags-on-commands). Because setting a flag by default still doesn't seem to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278296/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-flag-by-default-for-a-git-command

Comment: It did not work, as in it did not affect the behavior of gitk in the way it does the diff.

Comment: Ok. I didn't see the "gitk" in the title there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Now (after Sept 2014) update gitk `config_variables` and add `ignorespace`

https://github.com/git/git/commit/9fabefb1f3f658e77eb18afa3f95efe1a0ee8d0d

All these are flushed to `.gitk` file.

Comment: Man - I get a -15 for having comitted my own patch. Sigh. :)

Comment: @patthoyts sigh.. but yeah I understood what you are saying, just playing by the "rules" here

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit old but I found that question the other day googling, and the already accepted answer gave me a hint of how to do it.

No need to modify gitk itself: just edit your .gitk file (~/.config/git/gitk or ~/.gitk) and add:

```
set ignorespace 1
```

Comment: While adding this to `~/.config/git/gitk` has the desired effect on startup, it will be removed again on closing gitk. In `~/.gitk` it has no effect. I guess this only works for options listed as [config_variables](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f/gitk-git/gitk#L12382). So one would have to add it, as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865648/905686).

Answer (score 5):

All that is really required here is to persist the value of the variable set by the checkbutton on the UI. The following patch achieves this. Or you could just force the default to be true at line 11475 (`set ignorespace 1`).

```
From 54f9e800fe28cd6d5d0d44d4e2e561263cbf3407 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Pat Thoyts <patthoyts@users.sourceforge.net>
Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2011 11:39:01 +0000
Subject: [PATCH] gitk: persist the value of the ignorespace setting for
 diffs.

Signed-off-by: Pat Thoyts <patthoyts@users.sourceforge.net>
---
 gitk-git/gitk |    3 ++-
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

diff --git a/gitk-git/gitk b/gitk-git/gitk
index 2a92e20..29b18d9 100755
--- a/gitk-git/gitk
+++ b/gitk-git/gitk
@@ -2653,7 +2653,7 @@ proc savestuff {w} {
     global cmitmode wrapcomment datetimeformat limitdiffs
     global colors uicolor bgcolor fgcolor diffcolors diffcontext selectbgcolor
     global autoselect autosellen extdifftool perfile_attrs markbgcolor use_ttk
-    global hideremotes want_ttk
+    global hideremotes want_ttk ignorespace

     if {$stuffsaved} return
     if {![winfo viewable .]} return
@@ -2690,6 +2690,7 @@ proc savestuff {w} {
        puts $f [list set selectbgcolor $selectbgcolor]
        puts $f [list set extdifftool $extdifftool]
        puts $f [list set perfile_attrs $perfile_attrs]
+       puts $f [list set ignorespace $ignorespace]

        puts $f "set geometry(main) [wm geometry .]"
        puts $f "set geometry(state) [wm state .]"
--
1.7.8.msysgit.0
```

Comment: kudos for coming up with a patch for this, but I am unlikely to go to the trouble of custom building of gitk

Comment: It is a single file script - you can just edit /usr/local/bin/gitk or wherever it is.

Comment: yes - unless you copy it locally (eg: ~/bin/gitk). The patch could be sumbitted upstream but I suspect most people prefer having this reset each time they close the app. Possibly a decision for the maintainer to make.

Comment: I guess this is probably the best for now. What I do is that I *don't*  close the app and just reload it

Comment: Except the value will not be preserved over restarts of the application. The  `savestuff` function recreates it afresh each time you exit the application so your added line will get removed unless you modify the function as shown.