# How can I make gitk find string "IgnCase" by default

Tags: gitk

I often find myself selecting `IgnCase` in the pull-down on `gitk` GUI.  It'd be much easier for me if gitk's search is case insensitive by default.

So, how can I make `gitk` find string case-insensitive (`IgnCase` instead of `Exact`) by default?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the same problem as [making Ignore space change default option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8221877/905686).

In the [gitk script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitk-git/gitk)  the relevant option seems to be `findtype` ([set to "Exact" by default](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f/gitk-git/gitk#L2331)) but it is not under [config_variables](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f/gitk-git/gitk#L12382) which are loaded on startup and saved on closing.

Unfortunately, unlike for `ignorecase`, putting

```
set findtype [mc "IgnCase"]
```

into `~/.config/git/gitk` does not even set the option on startup.

While one might find commands to add to this config file to make it work, one would have to make sure to add them again after gitk overwrites the file on closing.