# How to pick with which key to sign a git push?

Tags: git, gnupg, git-push, signing

Git pushes can be signed with

```
git push --signed
```

Is it possible to specify with which gpg key to sign the push?  The manpage of `git push` does not specify anything and looking through the configuration options there only seems to be

```
user.signingkey
```

to specify the signing key for signed commits.

Comment: Make sure to use Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), especially if you are using HTTPS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110396/6309

Answer (score 1):

**No simple switch solution, sadly...**

But maybe you might be happy creating an alias for signed commits, such as:

```
$ git config --global alias.ptest '!git config user.signingkey KEY && git push --signed'
$ git config --global alias.pdev '!git config user.signingkey KEY2 && git push --signed'
```

Arguments should be passed to the `push` without issues.

Comment: Apparently, changing the environment variable for user and email may be enough. In https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gpg-interface.c#L145 if no key is specified in config, the user identity is used. So, try creating keys with some user name and email and push with modified `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`