# is there a commit hook for signing commits?

Tags: git, github, post-commit

I've seen lots of pre/post commit/push hooks, but I haven't seen one for [ensuring that the commit is signed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166916/659298). I don't know how to go about it, but I assume it might use `git [log|show] [commit(s)] --show-signature`.

disclaimer: yes, I've GTFS'ed and searched here on SO/SE/etc. yes, Torvalds doesn't like signed commits.

Comment: It wasn't in my GTFS results, would you please provide a reference for *"Torvalds doesn't like signed commits"*

Comment: @JeffPuckettII yeah- it's near the bottom of the SO answer I linked to.