# Autosign commits from git gui

Tags: git

Note: this is the git gui variant of ["Is there a way to “autosign” commits in Git with a GPG key?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161198/is-there-a-way-to-autosign-commits-in-git-with-a-gpg-key/10166916)

I configured git to autosign commits made from the command line by (globally) configuring `commit.gpgsign` to be true and `user.signingkey` to be the id of the key I want to sign with. This works great. But when I create a commit by opening `git gui` and hitting the commit button, the resulting commit is not signed.

Is there a way to make `git gui` automatically sign all commits it makes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup you have done should work. You may need to restart git gui for changes to global configs to take effect.

There was a bug related to this in git gui in version 2.9, but it's [fixed](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.1.txt#L38) in version 2.10.1.