# Is there a way to automatically verify git commits on each pull?

Tags: git, gnupg

This is the inverse of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161198/is-there-a-way-to-autosign-commits-in-git-with-a-gpg-key).

Is there an easy way to make Git always verify the pgp signature of the HEAD of any branch it pulls and fail if the signature is bad?

Much like `commit.gpgSign` but "in reverse".

Comment: Verify what?  If the settings are correct, how would a bad head have gotten in there in the first place?

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry, I meant PGP signatures, like how `commit.gpgSign` forces git to automatically sign commits and fails to commit if the signing process fails. I want the same thing but in reverse. I added more information to the question.

Comment: But how could that possibly occur?  You check the signature when you add something TO the repository.  Once it goes in, it can't go bad.  Code doesn't rot.

Comment: would the following: "run `git fetch` and check the validity of the remote branches you received" be acceptable ? if you receive a bad commit that way, it means it is already part of the central repository anyway

Comment: @TimRoberts That's not how signature verification works in git. See [this article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) for more information on what commit signatures are meant to protect.

Comment: @LeGEC I'm looking for ux that is similar to `commit.gpgSign` where verification would occur automatically on each pull, so unfortunately your solution is not sufficient. The purpose of this feature is to *automatically* detect a bad or non-compliant commit in upstream in a convenient way. If git doesn't support it, then "No, git doesn't current;y support this functionality" is an acceptable answer.

Comment: I'm sure the answer is "No, git doesn't support this functionality and most probably never will." Because nobody needs to check signatures at fetch time. Bad signatures should be verified *before* they're pushed into the central shared repository. I.e., they should be verified in the `pre-receive` hook in the upstream. Or at least in a CI immediately after push (and mark bad commits as failed in addition to unverified). If a project decided to allow bad signatures but you want to check them anyway — that's up to you. You write a post-fetch script. Git most probably will never implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script named `git-pull-and-verify` and add it to your `PATH`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

old_head="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
readonly old_head
# We’re using --ff-only because anything other than a fast-forward
# wouldn’t work. Merges and rebases result in new commits being created
# locally, and those commits would either be unsigned or signed by the
# machine that’s doing the pull.
git pull --ff-only
if ! git verify-commit HEAD
then
    echo ERROR: Failed to verify the commit that we just pulled. Reverting… 1>&2
    git reset --merge "$old_head"
fi
```

Afterwards, run `git pull-and-verify` to activate the script.

Comment: What about using `fetch` instead of `pull` to avoid resetting? And verifying all commits between `old_head` and `HEAD` if fetch brought many?

Comment: Seems like a good answer, but I would like to verify automatically on any pull operation that pulls in new commits. Since we're going to write a script anyway, would it make sense to install this script as a `post-merge` hook? If it works, then this is probably a valid answer that I would be more than happy to accept. I'm assuming you can roll HEAD back to the original commit if the verification fails.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken `post-merge` hook runs on any merge, not only after `pull`; and doesn't run for a fast-forward "merge".